# How to display parent records with its referenced entities(child reoord) in views table format

Tags: views, entities

I am new to drupal and I require help from you guys.

My requirement is :

I have one custom content type : Architecture and for that custom content type I have different entity references associated with it such as Data Architecture, Technology Architecture, Market Architecture.

so I have Architecture 1 as Parent architecture and then I have
Data architecture 1.1, Data architecture 1.2 are associated with Architecture 1 as entity references. Similarly Technology Architecture 1.1, Technology Architecture 1.2 are associated with Architecture 1.

So I need to display those in views in following format (table):

Architecture 1 -- other fields

Data architecture 1.1 -- other fields

Data architecture 1.2 -- other fields

Technology Architecture 1.1 -- other fields

Technology Architecture 1.2 -- other fields

Architecture 2 -- other fields

Data architecture 2.1 -- other fields

Data architecture 2.2 -- other fields

Technology Architecture 2.1 -- other fields

Technology Architecture 2.2 -- other fields

I have tried with adding relationship but no luck.

Please help.

Thanks in advance